# Spring Security Ajax Custom Filter

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, filter, spring-security

Below is sample code for handling AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter.
I am using spring-security with spring framework correctly.

```
private int customSessionExpiredErrorCode = 901;
if(authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()))
{
    logger.info("User session expired or not logged in yet");
    String ajaxHeader = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("X-Requested-With");

    if ("XMLHttpRequest".equals(ajaxHeader))
    {
        logger.info("Ajax call detected, send {} error code");
        HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;                           
        resp.sendError(this.customSessionExpiredErrorCode);
    }
    else
    {
        logger.info("Redirect to login page");
        throw ase;
    }
}
else
{
    throw ase;
}
```

*At Ui level, I am trying to capture 901 error code on header.jsp globally.*

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    400: function() {
      alert('400 status code! user error');
    },
    901: function() {
      alert('error 901');
    }
  }
});
```

*At browser console I can see `901 OK`*

Comment: you didnt mention about the problem that you are facing ? Are you receiving any error ?

Comment: I am not able to see these alert popup once 901 occurred.